# Path finding android application with prompt screen

Tags: android, path-finding

Hi there i have thoroughly search ed to try and find this answer but had no luck.

I am trying to achieve this:

- Android application that calculates the shortest path between two given points which the user can select.
- When displaying the path I want it to show each incremental step and prompt the user of the step to make (i.e move 2 squares right) before proceeding to the next step.
- I also want this movement drawn with a line to show the move just made.
- Finally I would want there to be movement between floors which the shortest path works out and simply prompts the user to stake stair node A to floor(x). Then continues the process on the next floor.

Background:

.The layout is a simple rectangle with three floors (luckily).
.The weighted sides are the same for each corresponding floor.

Is this possible? If so can you point me in a good direction of a tutorial of some sort.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible of course.

You could use a TableLayout to present a map on the screen, where each square could have it's own ID.

When the user clicks the squares, you should handle the click event and recognize which square was clicked by its ID.

Then do the calculations and update the view to display the results (ie change background color of the cells for example).

The question is too generic to get into any more details than that, but it doesn't sound like you're trying to do anything that's impossible.

Using real graphics to display a map and handle clicks on the graphics is much more complicated, but also doable. Follow these guides:

http://developer.android.com/training/building-graphics.html

http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply I appreciate the comment I want the application to look more an interactive map like:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtFrl_xdevw for exmaple (minus the sophistication of NFC!) as opposed to  looking like a grid.

Comment: That, of course is also possible, but much more complicated. You would have to use graphics to display the map, handle clicks on specific areas in the image, and have an underlying data structure that would represent the map that is displayed by the graphics. Android Devlopers has a good guide for using graphics http://developer.android.com/training/building-graphics.html, and for handling touch events on the graphics http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html.

Comment: Thanks for this advice it did help but im looking for something less theoory more visual

Comment: Sorry, what you're asking for is a bit too complicated a project... the guides are the best I can do. Let's see if someone has a more concrete example to link